# Javascript function if subtotal is lower than 50 or 0

Tags: cart

So I wrote a javascript function to display a message if the cart subtotal is less than 50. It works but I noticed that if the cart subtotal is 0 the javascript doesn't work and the message isn't displayed. I assume this is because the subtotal is NaN rather than 0. Not sure how to fix this though?

This is my js

```
function minus_number() {



    var amount = <?php echo $carttotal; ?>;

    if (amount < 50){
        var a  = document.querySelector("#spend");
        var first_number = 50.00;
        var second_number = <?php echo $carttotal; ?>;
        var result = (first_number).toFixed(2) - (second_number).toFixed(2);
        a.innerHTML = "Spend an extra £" + result.toFixed(2) + " for free delivery over £50!";
    }

    if (amount >= 50){
    var a = document.querySelector("#spend");
    var delivery_message = "YOUR ORDER QUALIFIES FOR FREE DELIVERY!";
    a.innerHTML = delivery_message; 
    }

}
window.addEventListener("load",minus_number());
```

Comment: What  is the value of `<?php echo $carttotal; ?>;` when subtotal is 0 ? Is it empty ?

Comment: Execute `<?php var_dump($carttotal); ?>;` to see the actual value

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value is `NaN` and then do your stuff.

```
if(isNaN(amount)){
    //your code here
}
```

You check if it is NaN and do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the total value numeric from PHP:

`var amount = <?php echo floatval($carttotal); ?>;`